# Tree ItemRenderer don't show tiny TitleWindows added to a BorderContainer in Renderer?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, mxml

I am facing some problem that I add some title widows to the **ItemRenderer**  of **tree**. but some time tree don't show those tiny title windows in tree item-renderer.. is this the issue that tree **re-use** its renderers..
(these windows are skinned like little cricles, and added specific to the `data` of item renderer.. these TitleWindows are added using `addElement()` to a `s:BorderContainer` in the renderer)

i add these windoes when data is set in

```
public function set data(data:xml):void
{
// add windows
}
```

and on show event..

```
protected function ShowHandler(event:Event):void
{
// add windows
}
```

is there any solution that.. every visible `ItemRenderer` has the windows in it...

Comment: It's difficult to advice something not seeing actual ItemRenderer code. In general your logic seems OK, but one needs to look into detail. Tiny working example will do.

Answer (score 0):

figuered out now.. i was removing all elements at creationComplete .. removed that. now its working good. thanks for helping  David Goshadze...